# No resource found that matches the given name with RadioGroup

Tags: android, xml

I'm having some trouble with a RadioGroup. For some reason it can't find the id of one of my RadioButtons.

The error:

```
Error:(18, 32) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'checkedButton' with value '@id/euro1').
```

My code:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/betGroup"
    android:checkedButton="@id/euro1">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/euro1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/euromoent1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/euromoent2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/euro2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/euro5small"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/euro5"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/euro10small"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/euro10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/euro20small"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/euro20" />

</RadioGroup>
```

So the line that is giving me an errror is:

```
android:checkedButton="@id/euro1">
```

Even though the RadioButton just below has that exact id. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `android:checkedButton="@id/euro1">` on radio group.

Add `android:checked="false"` to each of your RadioButtons. Whichever you want to check, add `android:checked="true"`

Like for checked button:

```
<RadioButton
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/euro5small"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/euro5"
    android:checked="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

For unchecked button:

```
<RadioButton
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/euro5small"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/euro5"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
```

Remove `android:checkedButton="@id/euro1">` this from radiogroup

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I ended up solving the problem by adding a plus in the id, like so:   android:checkedButton="@+id/euro1". I guess yours would have worked as well!